# Entity Framework 5 Include table that may or may not contain matches

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I already have everything working and displaying Vendors, but what I wanted to add now is a column showing which vendors have been selected or not (displayed as a checkbox column).  These selections are stored in another table that contains the ProfileID and UserName (domain user) that selected them.  So when the current domain user sees the table there will be matches for some Vendors and not for others.

What I tried was the following, but it gives me an error on UserName.

System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'UserName'

But it does contain this field and I have used it in other queries on this table (see model pic).

```
IQueryable<VendorProfile> query = _db.VendorProfiles
     .Include("VendorsSelected")
     .Where(x => x.VendorsSelected.UserName.Contains(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name))
     .OrderBy(v => v.ProfileID);
```

Any solution I use would have to account for the fact that there are matches and non-matches (null values)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select `UserName` *from* the collection `x.VendorsSelected`:

```
IQueryable<VendorProfile> query = _db.VendorProfiles
     .Include("VendorsSelected")
     .Where(x => x.VendorsSelected
                  .Select(v => v.UserName)
                  .Contains(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name))
     .OrderBy(v => v.ProfileID);
```

Comment: That sounds better, but something is off with the syntax as it does not like that. It now complains that ProfileID is undefiend in the last line. Seems like a ")" is missing but if I add one the whole .Where line complains (see updated post)

Comment: Forgot a parenthesis. Edited it.

Comment: Thx that fixed it!  Do you have any suggestions to my goal of displaying checkbox true/false values from this query.  The query above returns a sub collection of VendorsSelected if there is a match and an empty collection if no matches.  How would I best translate that into the view?

Comment: That should be dealt with in a view model or a DTO having a boolean value that you set according to the presence of vendors. But if you want detailed help on this I suggest you create a new question with a title that will attract the right audience. I'm more of a data access/services guy trying to avoid UIs as much as possible :).

Comment: One more question regarding the above query.  How can you modify it so that it specifies specific columns to be returned so the entire model is not returned.  I tried .Select(s => new { s.ProfileID, s.Name, s.CompanyName, s.City, s.State, s.DateCreated, s.VendorsSelected, s.VendorCategories }) without success

Comment: This too is a candidate for a new question. I don't know what you mean by _without success_ (error, wrong result, ...). `Select` is the right method, but if things "dont't work" we need more information to be able to help.

Comment: okay have posted new question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531583/entity-framework-selecting-specific-columns)

Comment: new question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536154/entity-framework-linq-return-column-based-on-record-in-fk-table)