# Entity Framework - Selecting specific columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have a successful query that links two tables with a where and orderby clause, but I wanted to add to just select specific columns instead of getting everything back.

PART 1
When I attempt this I get syntax errors on the orderby line, if I remove the orderby line the syntax errors move to the where line.

Error   3   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
            IQueryable<VendorProfile> query = _db.VendorProfiles
            .Include("VendorCategories")
            .Include("VendorsSelected")
            .Select(s => new  { s.ProfileID, s.Name, s.CompanyName, s.City, s.State, s.DateCreated, s.VendorsSelected, s.VendorCategories })
            .Where(x => x.VendorsSelected.Select(s => s.UserName).Contains(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name))
            .OrderBy(x => x.DateCreated);

       if (criteria.name != string.Empty)
            query = query.Where(v => v.Name.Contains(criteria.name));
        if (criteria.company != string.Empty)
            query = query.Where(v => v.CompanyName.Contains(criteria.company));
        if (criteria.startDate != null && criteria.endDate != null)
            query = query.Where(v => v.DateCreated > criteria.startDate && v.DateCreated < criteria.endDate);
        if (criteria.categories != null && !criteria.categoryMatchAll)
            query = query.Where(v => criteria.categories.AsQueryable().Any(cat => v.VendorCategories.Select(vendCat => vendCat.CategoryID).Contains(cat)));
        if (criteria.categories != null && criteria.categoryMatchAll)
            query = query.Where(v => criteria.categories.AsQueryable().All(cat => v.VendorCategories.Select(vendCat => vendCat.CategoryID).Contains(cat)));
        if (criteria.minorityType != null)
            query = query.Where(v => v.MinotiryOwned == criteria.minorityType);
        if (criteria.diversityClass != null)
            query = query.Where(v => v.DiversityClassification == criteria.diversityClass);

        return query.ToList();
```

PART 2
I also wanted to know if I could extract the selected columns into a view model class, so I tired this and I get same results as above on the orderby line

Error   4   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: use `var` instead of `IQueryable<VendorProfile>`?

Comment: @Pawel not sure i can, there are several selective where clauses that follow that query (added to OP). Can you suggest another workable solution to the above code?

Comment: why? var just lets the compiler to infer the correct type if you set the type explicitly and the type is not valid according to what you return. You can hover over `var` to see what the type really is. Currently it is like if you had a function that returns byte but you assigned the result to string variable (`string myVal = GetByte();`) if you use `var myVal = GetByte();` the compiler will know that `myVal` should be byte and will compile it to be a byte variable. In other words at runtime it will always be strongly typed but at compile time you ask the compiler to do the dirty work.

Comment: @Pawel if I make it var all the where clauses above give "An explicit conversion exists are you missing a cast"

Comment: Maybe you want to move the part **ANSWER** to an answer and mark it as accepted?

Comment: @GertArnold  done, but i cant accept my own answer.  I hope some LINQ   expert can help me with [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536154/entity-framework-linq-return-column-based-on-record-in-fk-table)

Comment: Please, could you clearly state what problem is left then?

Comment: @GertArnold the new problem was [posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536154/entity-framework-linq-return-column-based-on-record-in-fk-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWER**

I think you helped me stumble upon the fact that the types don't match. Making the IQueryable type and the select new type and the return type the SAME makes the syntax happy. Using var does not like.

```
public IEnumerable<BrowseVendorModel> SearchVendors(CustomSearchModel criteria)
{
    IQueryable<BrowseVendorModel> query = _db.VendorProfiles
        .Include("VendorCategories")
        .Include("VendorsSelected")
        .Select(s => new BrowseVendorModel
        {
            ProfileID = s.ProfileID,
            Name = s.Name,
            CompanyName = s.CompanyName,
            City = s.City,
            State = s.State,
            DateCreated = s.DateCreated,
            VendorsSelected = s.VendorsSelected,
            VendorCategories = s.VendorCategories
        })
        .Where(x => x.VendorsSelected.Select(s => s.UserName).Contains(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name))
        .OrderBy(x => x.DateCreated);

    if (criteria.name != string.Empty)
        query = query.Where(v => v.Name.Contains(criteria.name));
    if (criteria.company != string.Empty)
        query = query.Where(v => v.CompanyName.Contains(criteria.company));
    if (criteria.startDate != null && criteria.endDate != null)
        query = query.Where(v => v.DateCreated > criteria.startDate && v.DateCreated < criteria.endDate);
    if (criteria.categories != null && !criteria.categoryMatchAll)
        query = query.Where(v => criteria.categories.AsQueryable().Any(cat => v.VendorCategories.Select(vendCat => vendCat.CategoryID).Contains(cat)));
    if (criteria.categories != null && criteria.categoryMatchAll)
        query = query.Where(v => criteria.categories.AsQueryable().All(cat => v.VendorCategories.Select(vendCat => vendCat.CategoryID).Contains(cat)));
    if (criteria.minorityType != null)
        query = query.Where(v => v.MinotiryOwned == criteria.minorityType);
    if (criteria.diversityClass != null)
        query = query.Where(v => v.DiversityClassification == criteria.diversityClass);

    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first example requires `var` because you are changing the shape of the query by projecting into anonymous type. The second example can either use `var` or `IQueryable<VendorProfileViewModel>` because you are changing the shape of the query by projecting into `VendorProfileViewModel`.

Comment: Thx. I have the same problem as all the where clauses above that are below the orderby clause give errors as they depend upon IQueryable.  Is there another way that I can get both the building of queries and the selecting of fields to work?

Comment: But you still have `IQueryable<VendorProfileViewModel>`. If view model contains those fields you are using in where clauses it should just work.

Comment: I think you helped me stumble upon the fact that the types don't match.  Making the IQueryable type and the select new type both VendorProfileViewModel makes the syntax happy. Using var does not like. But still having problems with the returned view page.